# Change Passport version

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I need to change the version of my Passport to version 3.0, but I have no idea how I can do this! My project is using Laravel version 5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `composer.json` change version for `laravel/passport`, so, it will look like:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "laravel/passport": "^3.0",
    ...
},
```

and then update by typing `composer update`

Note: for laravel 5.6 you should use version 5.0